# query API in MongoDB,NODEJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
app.get('/search/:id',(req,res)=>{
            var db = client.db('dict');
            db.collection("word").find({'word': /^[req.params.id]/}).toArray(function(err, result){
                res.json(result);
            })
        })
```

Why it return all my words??

Comment: Try `.find({'word': new RegExp(req.params.id)})`

Comment: Nhưng nếu tìm từ có kí tự bắt đầu là req.params.id thì làm thế nào ạ?

Comment: What is your expectly? let's update your question to make it clear

Comment: if I want to return words starting with characters in req.params.id, how i do that??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a word with specific id :

```
 app.get('/search/:id',(req,res)=>{
                var db = client.db('dict');
                db.collection("word").find({'word': /req.params.id/},function (err, result)
                    res.json(result);
                })
            })
```

Comment: if I want to return words starting with characters in req.params.id, how i do that??

Comment: Can you give me the name of the field that you want to query by ?

Comment: @TríPhan can you share with me your model word schema, and do you want to find words starts with req.params.id or the exact value .?

Comment: I  want to find words starts with req.params.id

Comment: Can you share with me your model ?